# Combine 2 foreach loops

Tags: foreach

Im stuck in a 2 foreach loop and i can't pass to combine the values.

My question is, how can i combine the 2 foreach loop in this case?

```
public function getImageColors($id, $code)
{
    $values = $this->_storageModel->getOptions($id, $code);     
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
    $id = $product->getId();
    $productName = $product->getName();
    $productURL = $product->getProductUrl();
    $_gallery = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id)->getMediaGalleryImages();

    if (count($values) > 1) {
        foreach($values as $key => $val) {
            foreach ($_gallery as $_image) { 
                $url_image =  $_image->getUrl();
                    echo '<div data-main-image-src="'.$url_image.'" class="color'. $val . '" id="color' . $id . ' ></div>';
            }
        }
    }
    return '';
}
```

Another simple example:

```
$data1 = array('Blue','Red','Yellow','Black','White');
$data2 = array('blue.jpg','red.jpg','black.jpg','white.jpg');

foreach ($data1 as $val1) {
  $val1 = $color;
}

foreach ($data2 as $val2) {
  $val2 = $image;
}
```

the point is to get the values in a string but not concatenated.

need to be like : `echo <div class="<?php echo $color; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>"></div>`

how can i combine to echo the foreach value for both arrays ?

Comment: I do not understand the meaning of "i can't pass to combine the values." Can you provide more details? The function name begins with "get", but nothing useful is actually returned...

Comment: Please review the question, i have added another example.

Comment: is this coffee script?

Comment: No, is quite the same thing that i want to do, the only difference is that i have a result in array with key => value then i have another array that contain another info, but alwasy corelate with the first array, my issue is that the result is always: Blue = blue.jpg, Red = blue.jpg , Yellow = blue.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use foreach loop?? With for loop it can be easily done by this code

```
 $temp=count($data1)>count($data2)?count($data2):count($data1);
 for($i=0;$i<$temp;$i++)
 {
     echo $data1[$i].'->'.$data2[$i].'<br>';
 }
```